# Can Zuul Edge Server be used without Eureka / Ribbon

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

We have an infrastructure with service discovery and load balancing (i.e. server side with STM and weblogic cluster). Now we are in the process of refactoring into micro-services. We would need an API gateway which does basic routing to other microservices. Netflix Zuul looks a good candidate however I could not get Zuul working without Eureka - but we do not need Eureka since we already have service discovery and load balancing in place.

1. Is it possible to use Zuul without Eureka and Ribbon?
2. If yes please provide some guild-lines since the there's no mention about in the wiki.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible.You have to use `@EnableZuulProxy` on your config class and config it something like this :

```
zuul:
  routes:
    yourService:
      path: /yourService/**
      serviceId: yourService

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false

yourService:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080
```

Comment: You can also put `url` under `yourService`.

Comment: What would be the way if I am *not* using spring-cloud?

Comment: All these changes are in Zuul config right? Should I make any change in the microservice 'yourService'?

Comment: These are all in zuul, yes. No change needed for the downstream services. Also, spring has its own gateway now, if you are just starting I suggest checking it out: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/

Answer (score 3):

A sample usage can be like this:

```
shared.microservice.customer.service1.url=zttp://127.0.0.1:8080/shared/microservice/customer/

shared.microservice.customer.service2.url=zttp://127.0.0.1:8181/shared/microservice/customer/

ribbon.eureka.enabled = false

zuul.routes.customer-micro-service.path: /shared/microservice/customer/**

zuul.routes.customer-micro-service.serviceId: customers
customers.ribbon.listOfServers = 

zttp://ip:port1/shared/microservice/customer/,zttp://ip2:port2/shared/microservice/customer/
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Of course you can. Actually, **by default**, if you use **@EnableZuulProxy** with the Spring Boot Actuator, you enable two additional endpoints:

- Routes
- Filters

**application.yaml**

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      url: https://example.com/users_service
```

These simple url-routes do not get executed as a **HystrixCommand**, nor do they load-balance multiple URLs with **Ribbon**.

Yo can get more information from [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html).